# Autosearch all columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am in need of Excel VBA code that will autosearch all column in source workbook and then loop through each column name and then copy all values in each column and paste all values in another workbook under same column name (that too after doing autosearch all columns in the destination workbook).

I have written the code for copying and pasting values by specifying the each column but i need the code that is dynamic in nature and can be run for all the different excel sheets.

```
Sub CopyCurrentRegion()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Workbooks("Benchmark to Edit.xlsx").Worksheets("ANNEX A-1").cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks("Benchmark to Edit.xlsx").Worksheets("ANNEX A-1").Range("B7:B7" & lastrow).Copy
    Workbooks("Master to Edit.xlsb").Worksheets("IP Tape").Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Workbooks("Benchmark to Edit.xlsx").Worksheets("ANNEX A-1").Range("C7:C7" & lastrow).Copy
    Workbooks("Master to Edit.xlsb").Worksheets("IP Tape").Range("F9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the hard-coded sheet names (including their parents) and then call the Sub with sheets as parameters.

```
Sub testCopyCurrentRegion()
    Call CopyCurrentRegion(Workbooks("Benchmark to Edit.xlsx").Worksheets("ANNEX A-1"), _
        Workbooks("Master to Edit.xlsb").Worksheets("IP Tape"))
End Sub


Sub CopyCurrentRegion(ws_source As Worksheet, ws_target As Worksheet)
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = ws_source.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    ws_source.Range("B7:B7" & lastrow).Copy
    ws_target.Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    ws_source.Range("C7:C7" & lastrow).Copy
    ws_target.Range("F9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```